# When I try to run it says couldn't resolve all dependancies

Tags: android

[image]

Do I need to change the classpath?

Comment: In case your screenshot contains code means , just paste the code here. then only developers can access your code easily . so no need to add screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your `Project App (build.gradle)` file in your case open this file

## build.gradle(Project: SocialApp)

in this file change your dependency to this

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
```

**full code :**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and `Sync` the project it will work..

Comment: Now it is showing this error.
Gradle sync failed: Operation timed out. If you are behind an HTTP proxy, please configure the proxy settings either in IDE or Gradle.
           Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/layout-editor) suggests to use:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
}
```

Also, suggests to use:

> Ensure you have the latest Android Support Repository (version 32 or higher)

Update your libraries (remember to sync your Gradle project and update Gradle if necessary) - after this, it should start working.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you have to check the "contraint layout "repository support.check out like this.SDKmanager->SDKTools->check the

```
'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha4'
```

is installed or not..if it was not installed then make it install.then try to syn the project.